# The problem when running "rosrun uvc_camera camera_node"

Tags: ros, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I run the command "rosrun uvc_camera camera_node",it shows as below:

using default calibration URL

camera calibration URL: file:///home/sven/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml
Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/sven/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml]

Camera calibration file /home/sven/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml not found.

using default calibration URL
camera calibration URL: file:///home/sven/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml
Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/sven/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml]

Camera calibration file /home/sven/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml not found.

opening /dev/video0
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  couldn't open /dev/video0
Aborted

Is there anyone who can help me ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49545/the-problem-when-running-%22rosrun-uvc_camera-camera_node%22/) by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2012-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This probably is a duplicate of [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/38592/uvc_camera-initialization-problem/). An answer has been provided there. You should also be able to add yourself to the video group by typing

```
usermod -a -G video [YOUR_USER_NAME]
```

then logging out and back in.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1